# Blender port from SFM eyelashes

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

i am porting SFM models into blender, on this model i have a problem with the eyelashes. can someone help me fix this? it shows up like this on rendering also.

I have already tried applying particle and changing the emitter to hair but nothing happens or lines sprout from every part of the body

thank you in advance. below pictures apply. I feel like this is advanced but i would like to learn!

[image]

[image]